# ReferenceError: FormData is not defined at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

In the following I get an error...`ReferenceError: FormData is not defined
    at Object.

I'm not entirley sure what I am missing here as it looks correct to me.

```
export const setFlightAwareAlert = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    const body: {[key: string]: any} = request.body;
    const data = new FormData();
    Object.keys(body).forEach(key => data.append(key, body[key]));
    const alert_id = await axios.post(urls.setAlert, data, {
        headers: {
            'Authentication': `Basic ${btoa(`${FlightAwareCredentials.user}${FlightAwareCredentials.password}`)}`,
        },
        withCredentials: true
    });
    response.status(alert_id.status);
    response.json(alert_id.data);
});
```